# query in parse.com causing my app to quit

Tags: ios, xcode5, parse-platform

this code isnt working somehow

```
    //setup cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ParseExampleCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    PFObject *tempObject = [detailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   Cell.cellTitle.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"Exibitor"];
```

im getting

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell cellTitle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10d959830'
```

im trying to set up for when the user clicks a table item it will go to a detail view controller Exibitor is the correct class in the parse.com database

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        // Customize the table

        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"Exibitor";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        //self.textKey = @"name";

        // Uncomment the following line to specify the key of a PFFile on the PFObject to display in the imageView of the default cell style
         //self.imageKey = @"Logo";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        //self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        //self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        //self.objectsPerPage = 8;

    }


    return self;

}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    //_itemsArray = [NSMutableArray];
   // _detailArray = [NSMutableArray];

    [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveFromParse)];



    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

and then i have the rest of the code

```
- (void) retrieveFromParse {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Exibitor"];
    [query whereKey:@"Wedding" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            detailArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        }
        //[detailArray reloadData];
    }];
}
```

thats all i have ive took most of it out as im trying to find out what the heck is going on

Comment: could you expose your ParseExampleCell class ?

Comment: rest of code added. ps im new to parse.com. i have tried various ways to display the data. and i did display the data in one try but it wasn't in an array

Comment: you need to paste more code  and possibly also headers - problem seems that the cell is allocated just as UITableViewCell , not your cell class, which does not have .cellTitle as property.

Comment: If you're using a PFQueryTableViewController, you should have a 'queryForTable' method that returns a query.  You shouldn't be executing a query anywhere.  That's a separate issue though, your main problem is not Parse related.

Answer (score 0):

use this documentation [PFQueryTableViewController](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#ui-tables/iOS)
this healped me.
And also you can folow this tutorial [PFQueryTableViewController](http://www.appcoda.com/tag/pfquerytableviewcontroller/)